# Contract compilation fails during elemental battles tutorial

Tags: smart-contract, eosio.cdt, eosio-cpp

I have followed the elemental battles tutorial until lesson 2 step 4, and at the end of it, the tutorial instructs to compile the existing code with `eosio-cpp -o destination.abi source.cpp -abigen` (which makes no sense in that it seems to be putting a WASM into a .abi file)

I used `eosio-cpp -o cardgame.wasm cardgame.cpp -abigen` to try to compile but it did not work, giving me a long list of depreciation warnings (telling me to use eosio/* instead of eosiolib/*) and redefinition errors within the eosio files mostly.

At this point in the tutorial here is my code:
cardgame.hpp

```
#include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;
class [[eosio::contract]] cardgame : public eosio::contract {

  private:

    struct [[eosio::table]] user_info {
      name            username;
      uint16_t        win_count = 0;
      uint16_t        lost_count = 0;

      auto primary_key() const { return username.value; }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<name("users"), user_info> users_table;

    users_table _users;

  public:

    cardgame( name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds ):contract(receiver, code, ds),
                       _users(receiver, receiver.value) {}

    [[eosio::action]]
    void login(name username);

};
```

cardgame.cpp

```
#include "gameplay.cpp"

void cardgame::login(name username) {
  // Ensure this action is authorized by the player
  require_auth(username);

  // Create a record in the table if the player doesn't exist in our app yet
  auto user_iterator = _users.find(username.value);
  if (user_iterator == _users.end()) {
    user_iterator = _users.emplace(username,  [&](auto& new_user) {
      new_user.username = username;
    });
  } 
}

EOSIO_DISPATCH(cardgame, (login))
```

gameplay.cpp

```
#include "cardgame.hpp"
```

As hinted by the warning I tried to change eosiolib into eosio in my code:

```
#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
// #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>
```

But that still gives me the following error:

```
$ eosio-cpp -o cardgame.wasm cardgame.cpp -abigen
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, action <login> does not have a ricardian contract
Warning, action <login> does not have a ricardian contract
In file included from /tmp/cardgame.cpp:1:
/tmp/./gameplay.cpp:6:7: error: redefinition of '__insert_eosio_abi'
        void __insert_eosio_abi(unsigned long long r, unsigned long long c, unsigned long long a){eosio_assert_code(false, 1);}
             ^
/tmp/./cardgame.hpp:34:7: note: previous definition is here
        void __insert_eosio_abi(unsigned long long r, unsigned long long c, unsigned long long a){eosio_assert_code(false, 1);}
             ^
1 error generated.
/usr/opt/eosio.cdt/1.6.1/bin/wasm-ld: error: cannot open /tmp/cardgame.cpp.o: No such file or directory
```

I however noticed that if I indicate the output wasm file to have a different name, the compilation would succeed(WHY?). However the .abi file is absent and therefore it is impossible to use this contract.

```
$ eosio-cpp -o cardgamee.wasm cardgame.cpp -abigen
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
Warning, empty ricardian clause file
$ ls
cardgame.cpp  cardgamee.wasm  cardgame.hpp  gameplay.cpp
```

What am I doing wrong in this case? How can I successfully compile this contract?

Comment: I just did a git pull of the lesson 2 and I got the exact same error as you, and the same solution, this is weird

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have find the solution, it was a classic header include problems, so you just have to add -I. at the end like

eosio-cpp -o cardgame.wasm cardgame.cpp -abigen -I.

more information about the issue here:

https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/issues/489

Comment: This does not seem to work. I still get the exact same error about redefining `__insert_eosio_abi`. Were you able to replicate this error before you used `-I.` ?

Comment: yes I got the same error from doing a git pull of the lesson 2 then I fixed it with this solution, still got all the warning though, you should pull a new copy without your old modification/test

Comment: It still won't work for me after I copied all the code directly from the repository. Keeping `eosiolib` still gives me warnings and errors (you only mention warnings, does your compilation succeed at that point?), and using `eosio` gives me that error I mentioned again. I am using the cdt 1.6.1, is it possible I made a mistake during the setup?

Comment: Maybe you were not in the right directory ? I put all the step from start to end here https://pastebin.com/prKjY5pE

Comment: I just followed your steps and still cannot compile successfully. I get 26 warnings and 1 error (the same one): https://pastebin.com/JLmqwene . When putting our warnings into a diffchecker, one difference stood out, although I am not sure it is relevant: you have `In file included from ././gameplay.cpp:1:   In file included from ./cardgame.hpp:1:` but mine is `In file included from /tmp/./gameplay.cpp:2: 
  In file included from ././cardgame.hpp:1:`

Comment: Have you tried "-I./" or just "-I" flags ? show me a pastebin of "eosio-cpp -v"

Comment: None of `-I./` or `-I` works, here is the pastebin: https://pastebin.com/vwNHvnhY

Comment: At this point I think you gonna have more luck asking in the c++ section of stackoverflow,

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround for people who might have the same problem in the future (I do not consider this a real "solution"):

Simply put all the code into one file like so :

cardgame.cpp

```
// #include "gameplay.cpp"

#include <eosio/eosio.hpp>
// #include <eosiolib/eosio.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace eosio;
class [[eosio::contract]] cardgame : public eosio::contract {

  private:

    struct [[eosio::table]] user_info {
      name            username;
      uint16_t        win_count = 0;
      uint16_t        lost_count = 0;

      auto primary_key() const { return username.value; }
    };

    typedef eosio::multi_index<name("users"), user_info> users_table;

    users_table _users;

  public:

    cardgame( name receiver, name code, datastream<const char*> ds ):contract(receiver, code, ds),
                       _users(receiver, receiver.value) {}

    [[eosio::action]]
    void login(name username);

};

void cardgame::login(name username) {
  // Ensure this action is authorized by the player
  require_auth(username);

  // Create a record in the table if the player doesn't exist in our app yet
  auto user_iterator = _users.find(username.value);
  if (user_iterator == _users.end()) {
    user_iterator = _users.emplace(username,  [&](auto& new_user) {
      new_user.username = username;
    });
  } 
}

EOSIO_DISPATCH(cardgame, (login))
```

This probably betrays some programming best practice, but this is only a workaround and since smart contracts should be generally pretty simple and compact, it should not result in a monstrously large file.